# Primary key issue and other errors when creating SQL database in PostgreSQL 9.3.14

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.3.14 on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS on pgAdmin III. I wrote some code in Sublime Text, saved it as a plain text, and am running it via the terminal. **Before I run the code, I make sure to go into pgAdmin and delete/drop the database.**

Here is my code:

```
CREATE DATABASE movie_info;

CREATE TABLE movie_attributes
(
Title varchar(255),
Duration integer,
IMDB_Rating integer,
Release_Date integer
);

ALTER TABLE movie_attributes ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);

INSERT INTO movie_attributes (Title, Duration, IMDB_Rating, Release_Date)
VALUES ('Zoolander', 105, 6.6, 2001);

INSERT INTO movie_attributes (Title, Duration, IMDB_Rating, Release_Date)
VALUES ('Training Day', 122, 7.7, 2001);

INSERT INTO movie_attributes (Title, Duration, IMDB_Rating, Release_Date)
VALUES ('Band of Brothers', 705, 9.5, 2001);

INSERT INTO movie_attributes (Title, Duration, IMDB_Rating, Release_Date)
VALUES ('The Shawshank Redemption', 144, 9.3, 1994);



CREATE TABLE cinema_info
(
id integer CONSTRAINT cinema_info_pk PRIMARY KEY,
Title varchar(255),
Theatre_Number integer UNIQUE,
Showtime varchar(255)
);

ALTER TABLE cinema_info ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);


INSERT INTO cinema_info (Title, Theatre_Number, Showtime)
VALUES ('Zoolander', 2, '5:30');

INSERT INTO cinema_info (Title, Theatre_Number, Showtime)
VALUES ('Training Day', 3, '6:30');

INSERT INTO cinema_info (Title, Theatre_Number, Showtime)
VALUES ('Band of Brothers', 1, '7:30');

INSERT INTO cinema_info (Title, Theatre_Number, Showtime)
VALUES ('The Shawshank Redemption', 4, '5:30');
```

Here are the errors I'm receiving in Terminal:

```
psql -f ~/Documents/Sublime\ Text\ Docs/2016_09_09\ -\ Test\ Movie\ Database\
> 
CREATE DATABASE
psql:/home/ryan/Documents/Sublime Text Docs/2016_09_09 - Test Movie Database:9: ERROR:  relation "movie_attributes" already exists
psql:/home/ryan/Documents/Sublime Text Docs/2016_09_09 - Test Movie Database:11: ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "movie_attributes" are not allowed
psql:/home/ryan/Documents/Sublime Text Docs/2016_09_09 - Test Movie Database:14: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, Zoolander, 105, 7, 2001).
psql:/home/ryan/Documents/Sublime Text Docs/2016_09_09 - Test Movie Database:17: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, Training Day, 122, 8, 2001).
psql:/home/ryan/Documents/Sublime Text Docs/2016_09_09 - Test Movie Database:20: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, Band of Brothers, 705, 10, 2001).
psql:/home/ryan/Documents/Sublime Text Docs/2016_09_09 - Test Movie Database:23: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, The Shawshank Redemption, 144, 9, 1994).
psql:/home/ryan/Documents/Sublime Text Docs/2016_09_09 - Test Movie Database:33: ERROR:  relation "cinema_info" already exists
psql:/home/ryan/Documents/Sublime Text Docs/2016_09_09 - Test Movie Database:35: ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "cinema_info" are not allowed
psql:/home/ryan/Documents/Sublime Text Docs/2016_09_09 - Test Movie Database:39: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, Zoolander, 2, 5:30).
psql:/home/ryan/Documents/Sublime Text Docs/2016_09_09 - Test Movie Database:42: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, Training Day, 3, 6:30).
psql:/home/ryan/Documents/Sublime Text Docs/2016_09_09 - Test Movie Database:45: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, Band of Brothers, 1, 7:30).
psql:/home/ryan/Documents/Sublime Text Docs/2016_09_09 - Test Movie Database:48: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, The Shawshank Redemption, 4, 5:30).
```

Since I'm dropping the database every time, I'm not sure how "movie_attributes" already exists, and I'm not sure how I have null primary key values since I'm adding the primary key with the ALTER TABLE line. I'm also stumped as to how there are multiple primary keys when I'm only adding one per table.

I've tried a number of different approaches, but myself and everyone I've talked to cannot get it to work. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

**EDIT:** Following Doon's advice, I'm now receiving this error:

```
psql -f ~/Documents/Sublime\ Text\ Docs/2016_09_09\ -\ Test\ Movie\ Database\ Fixed
CREATE DATABASE
psql:/home/ryan/Documents/Sublime Text Docs/2016_09_09 - Test Movie Database Fixed:10: ERROR:  relation "movie_attributes" already exists
psql:/home/ryan/Documents/Sublime Text Docs/2016_09_09 - Test Movie Database Fixed:12: ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "movie_attributes" are not allowed
psql:/home/ryan/Documents/Sublime Text Docs/2016_09_09 - Test Movie Database Fixed:15: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, Zoolander, 105, 7, 2001).
psql:/home/ryan/Documents/Sublime Text Docs/2016_09_09 - Test Movie Database Fixed:18: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, Training Day, 122, 8, 2001).
psql:/home/ryan/Documents/Sublime Text Docs/2016_09_09 - Test Movie Database Fixed:21: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, Band of Brothers, 705, 10, 2001).
psql:/home/ryan/Documents/Sublime Text Docs/2016_09_09 - Test Movie Database Fixed:24: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, The Shawshank Redemption, 144, 9, 1994).
psql:/home/ryan/Documents/Sublime Text Docs/2016_09_09 - Test Movie Database Fixed:35: ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "cinema_info" are not allowed
LINE 4: id integer CONSTRAINT cinema_info_pk PRIMARY KEY,
                   ^
psql:/home/ryan/Documents/Sublime Text Docs/2016_09_09 - Test Movie Database Fixed:37: ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "movie_attributes" are not allowed
psql:/home/ryan/Documents/Sublime Text Docs/2016_09_09 - Test Movie Database Fixed:41: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, Zoolander, 2, 5:30).
psql:/home/ryan/Documents/Sublime Text Docs/2016_09_09 - Test Movie Database Fixed:44: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, Training Day, 3, 6:30).
psql:/home/ryan/Documents/Sublime Text Docs/2016_09_09 - Test Movie Database Fixed:47: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, Band of Brothers, 1, 7:30).
psql:/home/ryan/Documents/Sublime Text Docs/2016_09_09 - Test Movie Database Fixed:50: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, The Shawshank Redemption, 4, 5:30).
```

Here's the revised code:

```
CREATE DATABASE movie_info;

CREATE TABLE movie_attributes
(
id serial PRIMARY KEY,
Title varchar(255),
Duration integer,
IMDB_Rating integer,
Release_Date integer
);

INSERT INTO movie_attributes (Title, Duration, IMDB_Rating, Release_Date)
VALUES ('Zoolander', 105, 6.6, 2001);

INSERT INTO movie_attributes (Title, Duration, IMDB_Rating, Release_Date)
VALUES ('Training Day', 122, 7.7, 2001);

INSERT INTO movie_attributes (Title, Duration, IMDB_Rating, Release_Date)
VALUES ('Band of Brothers', 705, 9.5, 2001);

INSERT INTO movie_attributes (Title, Duration, IMDB_Rating, Release_Date)
VALUES ('The Shawshank Redemption', 144, 9.3, 1994);



CREATE TABLE cinema_info
(
id serial PRIMARY KEY,
id integer CONSTRAINT cinema_info_pk PRIMARY KEY,
Title varchar(255),
Theatre_Number integer UNIQUE,
Showtime varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO cinema_info (Title, Theatre_Number, Showtime)
VALUES ('Zoolander', 2, '5:30');

INSERT INTO cinema_info (Title, Theatre_Number, Showtime)
VALUES ('Training Day', 3, '6:30');

INSERT INTO cinema_info (Title, Theatre_Number, Showtime)
VALUES ('Band of Brothers', 1, '7:30');

INSERT INTO cinema_info (Title, Theatre_Number, Showtime)
VALUES ('The Shawshank Redemption', 4, '5:30');
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when creating your tables, you are not creating anything that auto increments your primary keys (id).  You should use either `serial` or `bigserial` which create sequences behind the scenes for you..

also when you create the database, it doesn't automatically connect you to it,  so after creating you need to connect to the new DB using `\c`.  What is probably happening is that you are creating the tables in your template or default database, hence the duplicate keys, relation exists errors..

```
CREATE DATABASE movie_info;
\c movie_info

CREATE TABLE movie_attributes
(
id serial PRIMARY KEY,
Title varchar(255),
Duration integer,
IMDB_Rating integer,
Release_Date integer
);

CREATE TABLE cinema_info
(
id serial PRIMARY KEY,
Title varchar(255),
Theatre_Number integer UNIQUE,
Showtime varchar(255)
);
```

should fix the current issue.

as for the multiple primary keys, you specify id as primary key in the DDL, then are trying to re-add.  Hence the multiple keys (even though they are the same key..)

another option would be to specify the ids, on  your insert statements.

Comment: thanks for your help and prompt response. I am still receiving some errors. I've edited my initial post with the revised code and errors. I'm still at a total loss as to what to do - did I do anything wrong? I have tried with and without the alter table strings (i.e. "ALTER TABLE movie_attributes ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);"). Thanks again.

Comment: are you 100% sure that you are dropping the database?  since the errors seem to indicate that it already exists, and therefore the create statements are not running..

Comment: think I figured it out. you are not connecting to the new database, after creation. see my latest edit.

Comment: Wow, it worked - thank you so much @Doon ! None of the SQL tutorials I found mentioned the \c bit.